# How to logon from a Serviceapplication, without knowing Outlookversion (2010,2013,2016,etc) in advance

Tags: delphi, outlook-redemption

Im writing a Service-Application that should monitor one or more ExchangeMailboxes for incoming Mails to perform some action with those.
The Service will run in different environments, which means i need to support Outlook 2010 to 2019.

How can i reliably Logon to a Session from a Service-Application no matter the Outlookversion?

I have the following code that works for Outlook 2010 but not 2016.
The ExchangeServer is the same and using version 2010.

```pascal
for MailboxName in MailboxesToMonitor do
begin
  Session := RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession;
  Session.LogonExchangeMailbox(MailboxName, 'ExchangeServerName'); // works for 2010, but not 2016
  DefaultStore := Session .Stores.DefaultStore;
  if (LDefaultStore.StoreKind in [skPrimaryExchangeMailbox, skDelegateExchangeMailbox]) then
  begin
    MailboxStore := TRDOExchangeMailBoxStore.Create(Self);
    try
      MailboxStore.ConnectTo(DefaultStore as IRDOExchangeMailboxStore);
      MailboxStore.OnNewMail := RDOStoreOnNewMail;
    except
      LMailboxStore.Free;
      raise;
    end;
    Sessions.Add(Session);
  end;
end;
```

- `Session.LogonExchangeMailbox` throws a *MAPI_E_UNKNOWN_FLAGS* error with Outlook 2016 installed.
- `Session.Logon` didnt work in a ServiceApplication.
- `Session.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` throws:

  1. EOleSysError: Expected HTTP_STATUS_REDIRECT, recieved 403
  2. EIdDnsResolverError: DNS Server Reports Query Name Error
  3. EHTTPError: HTTP error 401 from `https://autodiscover.domain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`
  4. EOleSysError: GetAutodiscoverUrlFromDns error: DNS lookup error using xx.xx.xx.xx: DNS Server Reports Query Name Error
  5. EOleSysError: GetAutodiscoverForEmailAddress: There are no autodiscover servers in the AD for this address

Comment: If you want an outlook independend working setup, use EWS API, here is [an example with powershell](https://seanonit.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/using-powershell-and-ews-to-monitor-a-mailbox/)

Comment: Error 401 means the credentials are wrong. What do you pass for the first and second paraeters?

Comment: good point, i tried `Session.LogonHostedExchangeMailbox('me@company.com', 'me@company.com', '<password>');` and that didnt work, it did work though with using 'Domain\Username' as `UserName`parameter, so i needed to use *NTLM authentication*. Is there a way to check which authentication-method is needed beforehand or do i just need to try and see what works, if i dont know what is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that `LogonExchangeMailbox` connects to the server in the old RPC mode, which the latest versions of Exchange Server no longer support.

You need to use `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` for Exchange 2013 / 2016 / 2019 - it connects in the PRC-over-HTTP or MAPI-over-HTTP mode. You will need to have at least Outlook 2010 SP2, 2013 SP1, or 2016 / 2019 for LogonHostedExchangeMailbox to work.

Comment: In the current environment Exchange 2010 is used, does that mean `LogonExchangeMailbox` is the correct way here? This works on a machine with Outlook 2010 but not on a machine with Outlook 2016

Comment: LogonExchangeMailbox  should still work... Does LogonHostedExchangeMailbox  work for your Exchange 2010 server?

Comment: `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox` does not work for my Exchange 2010 server, please see the edited question for the errors im getting.